# Federated identity AAD to ADFS redirect | UWP App

Tags: uwp, azure-active-directory, adfs

We are using ADAL for .NET to authenticate our UWP App against Azure AD. The Azure AD is synced from the internal AD (with Azure AD Connect), and federated with AD FS.

When I call 'AcquireTokenAsync'...

1. The web view pops up as expected.
2. The user is prompted to enter their email on the Microsoft Azure AD login page.
3. When a domain user enters their username, the expected 'We're taking you to your organization's sign in page...' message appears.
4. User is redirected to the organization's actual customized sign in page

So my ask is: Can we skip the first prompt of the default Azure AD page (#2) and redirect directly to the organization's login page?

I am able to achieve the same in an web UI app by using custom OpenIdConnectEvents and setting the domain name (*context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint*). But in this client app scenario not able to figure out what to do. Any points welcome.

UWP code is as simple as...

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/abccompany.onmicrosoft.com");

AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync("resource", "clientId", new Uri("redirect url for client app"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, false));

// Get token from: ar.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. thanks. "**domain_hint**" is the trick.

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync("resource", "clientId", new Uri("redirect url for client app"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, false), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, "domain_hint=*******.net");
```

Comment: Yeah, if you specify `domain_hint=company.com`, Azure AD finds the domain in the tenant, figures out it is a federated domain, and redirects to the ADFS login screen. This is also called "skipping Home Realm Discovery".